# Append to const char* bytes?

Tags: objective-c, char, nsdata

I'm needing to get all of the bytes from an `NSData` object after the 12th index.

So far I have

```
const char* fileBytes = (const char*)[imageData bytes];
NSUInteger length = [imageData length];
NSUInteger index;


NSMutableString *byteString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes: %@", imageData.description]];

for (index = 12; index<length; index++) { //Grabba returns a 12 byte header.
    char aByte = fileBytes[index];
    [byteString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", aByte]];
}
```

But what I'd really like to do is create a `const char*` and just append each byte at index 12 till the end to it. How can I append bytes to a series of bytes?

Comment: Please write 100 times: "C is **not** Objective-C is not C# is not C++ is not C."!

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. I'm using Objective-C & C code, am I not? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Your question is Objective-C-specific. Htey share some syntax, but that is true even for Python and Ruby. Not sure about Objective-C, but C++ for instance has quite some semantics different from C - with same syntax. Can you prove this is not the same for Objective-C? In other words: Is **every** C program a valid Objective-C program with **identical** semantics? Note that does include **all* standard libraries.

Comment: Use `NSMutableData`.

Comment: To add to what @rmaddy said: `NSString` is *not* suitable for storing bytes.

Comment: It's not particularly relevant to this question, but to answer @Olaf: yes, every C program is a valid Objective-C program with identical semantics. Objective-C is a strict superset of C. Objective-C++ is, likewise, a strict superset of C++, which means its semantics differ from Objective-C in just the same ways that C++'s differ from C. That said, if a question contains Objective-C code, it shouldn't be tagged with C, since C programmers can't be expected to deal with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use some standard C library calls. You know how many bytes there are in the `NSData` object, so you can alloc the storage you need and then memcpy all the bytes from the 12th one on.

```
NSUInteger length = [data length];
char* theBytes = malloc(sizeof(char)*(length-11));
memcpy(theBytes,fileBytes+11,length-11);
```

theBytes cannot be a const char* because of course it is not constant until after you have called memcpy.

Remember to call free when you are done with the string.